# Can Angular send a plot to the backend

Tags: javascript, python, angular, image, charts

I am using Angular and Javascript on the frontend, and use AgChartOptions to create a plot. Now I wonder whether I can make this chart a picture file and send it to the backend, presumable python. Is this possible?If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, charts API provides `getChartImageDataURL` method which returns image as data URL, then you can submit it to backend as string for example.